# How to apply transformations on a Spark Dataframe to generate tuples?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following sampleDF DataFrame in Spark Scala:

```
+-------+--------+------------------
|col1   |    col2|             col3|
+-------+--------+------------------
|    200|20200218|batched-202002180|
|    207|20200218|batched-202002190|
+-------+--------+------------------
```

Now I am collecting values for a single col doing the following operation in Spark: 
Which gives the following o/p:

```
scala> val result = newDF.select("col3").collect.map(row => row(0).toString)
result: Array[String] = Array(batched-202002180, batched-202002190)
```

Now, How do I also select the other two columns col1 and col2 and collect all three columns as an array of tuples? For brevity I have shown just 3 cols in the above DF. We can expect there to be more than 3 cols.

Expected output:

```
Array((200, 20200218, "batched-202002180"), (207, 20200218, "batched-202002190"))
```

Comment: `newDF.rdd.map(r => (r(0),r(1),r(2))).collect()`?

Comment: @ernest_k yes that works. However My first two columns are longs and last column is a String. So I have created a column list 
```cols = Seq(col1, col2, col3)
val result = newDF.select(cols.head, cols.tail: _*).rdd.map(r => (r(0),r(1),r(2).toString))collect() ```
However I get an error if I do a `.toLong` or `.map(_.toLong)`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do similar as below

```
newDF.map(r => (r.getAs[Long](0),r.getAs[Long](1),r.getAs[String](2))).collect()
```

Will give you `Array[(Long, Long, String)]`

If you want to convert to String you can use

```
val result = newDF.select(cols.head, cols.tail: _*).map(r => (r.getLong(0).toString,r.getLong(1).toString,r.getString(2))).collect()
```

Will give you `Array[(String, String, String)]`

Answer (score 1):

Without converting to `rdd`. Please check below code.

```
scala> df
.withColumn("col1","col1".cast("long"))
.withColumn("col2","col2".cast("long")).show(false)
+----+--------+-----------------+
|col1|col2    |col3             |
+----+--------+-----------------+
|200 |20200218|batched-202002180|
|207 |20200218|batched-202002190|
+----+--------+-----------------+


scala> df.map(r => (r.getAs[Long](0),r.getAs[Long](1),r.getAs[String](2))).collect()
res229: Array[(Long, Long, String)] = Array((200,20200218,batched-202002180), (207,20200218,batched-202002190))
```

Comment: The first two values are longs. How do I modify in that case? @Srinivas